# modifying arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

So I'm trying to figure out how to take user input thru the Scanner object, place it in each slot of an array, then read those numbers back to the user plus one. Problem is I have to use a a loop for the read back statement.Heres what I have so far. I figured out the first loop fine with the scanner, but I don't know how to modify each element in the array using a loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Lab7 
{
public static void main(String [] Args)
{

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your 5 integers: ");


    int index =0; 
    final int SIZE = 5; 
    int[] arrayOfSize = new int[SIZE]; 


    while(index<arrayOfSize.length )
    {
        arrayOfSize[index]=console.nextInt();
        index++; 

    }

    System.out.println("Processing each array element...");
```

Comment: You don't need to modify them, you can print them modified `for(int i=0;i<array.length;I++) System.out.printf("index %d is %d plus one%n", i, array[i]+1);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the below, Here i am first taking the user input integers and increasing it by `1` and then storing it in the `a[]` array of integers code for it is `int j = scanner.nextInt();
            // store it in array as incremented by 1.
            a[i]=j+1;`,

which i am iterating later to get the user input value+1 for example **if user input was 1, then in array it would be stored as 2**  :-

Complete runnable code is below with the comments and sample input and output :-

```
public class SOTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create scanner object
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // create an array of 10 integers
        int a[] = new int[10];
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            int j = scanner.nextInt();
            // store it in array as incremented by 1.
            a[i]=j+1;
        }
        // Now array of integers have the user input value+1.
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            System.out.println(" "+ a[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

My program input and output is below, which will make it easy to understand :-

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 11 printing user input value by adding 1 to it  2 3
>   4 5 6 7 8 9 10 12

Answer (score 0):

I Think this code will easily understand by you

```
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class Demo
    {
    public static void main(String [] Args)
    {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter your 5 integers: ");


    int index =0; 
    final int SIZE = 5; 
    int[] arrayOfSize = new int[SIZE]; 


    while(index<arrayOfSize.length )
    {
        arrayOfSize[index]=console.nextInt();
        index++; 

    }

    System.out.println("Processing each array element...");

    for(int i=0;i<arrayOfSize.length;i++){
        System.out.print((arrayOfSize[i]+1)+" ");//(arrayOfSize[i]+1)this will take current value stored in array and add 1 to it
    }

  }  
}
```